# Action_Send Intent not work for Activity

Tags: android

i use this code for share my content.I can't use this for my Activity, but i can use this for my fragment ! when i call that in my activities, app crashed ! please help me, thanks .

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = itemsArrayList.get(position).getDes();
                //sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "اشتراک با"));
```

My logcat errors :

> 11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1244)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1231)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam.adapter_common$4.onClick(adapter_common.java:138)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>   11-10 01:57:32.597 11723-11723/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: please share your logcat error.

Comment: ok , in added that Deepak Goyal .

Comment: try using `getActivity()` instead of `context`....and let me know....

Comment: Deepak Goyal , don't work yet .

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you are not using an activity as your context you must include the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as the error says.  Since you are doing this from a fragment you have to add:

```
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: What is the logcat output now?

Comment: i added second logcat .

Comment: That error shouldn't be showing up still.  Post your update code.